# Please help in probability

Tags: probability

A number is picked uniformly and randomly from a set of five-digit natural numbers. What is the probability that at least one of the digits of the number thus picked is 0?
I solved by taking numerator as 1st digit we have 9 options, then we select 1 out of remaining 4 digits and lock it for zero so 4c1 and remaining three digits have 10* 10 * 10 options, so probablity = 36000/90000
but my friend explained the count of 5 digit natural numbers that don’t have any 0 digit in any position = 9^5 = 59049
Therefore, 90000 - 59049 = 30951 5 digit natural numbers have at least one position occupied by a 0.
Therefore, the probability of selecting a 5 digit natural number from the set of all 5 digit natural numbers such that at least one position of the selected number is occupied by a 0 digit = 30951/90000 = 3439/10000

I cant understand where my approach is wrong? Its 9 options for first digit, then 1 option of zero for any of four digits and then 10 options each for remaining three digits .. :-((

Comment: "a set" of 5 digit numbers? or "the set (of all)" 5 digit numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by "five-digit natural number"? Is 00000 one of them?

Comment: No its starting from a non zero digit

Comment: Because you calculated the numbers with multiple zeros more than once. For example the number d$00$dd (where d is a digit). You calculate it twice: firstly as d$0$ddd and then as dd$0$dd.
Your approach is ok, but you need to use inclusion-exclusion formula then:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^4(-1)^{n-1}C(4,n)*9*10^{4-n}
$$

Comment: It's from 10000 to 99999, this makes it 90000 numbers

Comment: I can't understand Inclusion exclusion formula, I have always used my approach in all questions and got correct answers  it's just what options I have for that particular space

Comment: Is there a good book on probability except bliztein

Comment: Help brothers help

Comment: As others have remarked, your method is wrong as it overcounts those numbers with more than one $0$.  Easier to work from the complement.  The probability that your number has no $0$ is $\left( \frac 9{10}\right)^4$.

Comment: Yes but I wanted to stick to my approach

Comment: Then you need to use Inclusion Exclusion, as others have said.  Or count separately those with exactly one $0$, exactly two $0's$, and so on.

Comment: Can anyone give me a tutorial on Inclusion exclusion, specially with above question,  on YouTube everyone is drawing venn diagrams,  I cant find it

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out, the complement approach is the easiest.

If you want to stick to your approach, *and also avoid inclusion-exclusion*, you can *add up* cases with **exactly** one digit zero, two digits zero, etc to get

$\binom41*9^4 + \binom42*9^3 + \binom43*9^2 +\binom44*9^1 = 30951$ as the numerator,

and $Pr = \Large\frac{30951}{90000}$

**PS**

You must definitely learn inclusion-exclusion, as it is an essential tool in your armoury, but don't start with this problem, as it is not a simple one because place values of the $0's$ will also come into the picture.

In fact, learning apart, my credo is that the simplest way to solve a problem is best, and the simplest here, as you know, is using the complement to get $ Pr = \Large\frac{90000-9^5}{90000}$